# Pagination in CGridView in yii

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I wanna show data through CGridView with pagination..

Here the problem is that the dataprovider is an array ratherthan CArrayDataProvider or CDataProvider..

How to add pagination if dataprovider is an array as shown below

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'family-record-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$arr[1],

            'enableSorting' => false,
            'columns'=>
            array()
          ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **CGridView** in your view file.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'family-record-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
            'afterAjaxUpdate'   => 'function(){}',
            'htmlOptions'       => array('class' => 'form-inline', 'role' => 'grid'),
            'ajaxUrl'           => Yii::app()->createUrl('controllername/actioname'), 
            'ajaxUpdate'        => true,
            'enablePagination'  => true,
            "summaryText"       => true,
            'itemsCssClass'     => 'responsive dataTable', // Item CSS Class
            "template"          => "{items}\n{summary}{pager}",
            "summaryText"       => "Showing {start} to {end} of {count} entries",
            'pagerCssClass'     => '', // Page CSS Class
            'pager'             => array(
                'class' => 'CLinkPager',
                'maxButtonCount'    => 5,
                'nextPageLabel'     => 'Next',
                'prevPageLabel'     => 'Prev',
                'firstPageLabel'    => 'First',
                'lastPageLabel'     => 'Last',
            ),
            'selectableRows'    => 2,
            'enableSorting' => false,
            'columns'=>array()
            )
);
```

Comment: it doesnt effect anything ....this doesnt works and shows all the data....

Comment: you can set your `$model-search()` inside page set.

Comment: it is showing first 20 records fine .but not showing hyperlinks that is page numbers fr pagination....